# SharedFlow : mapLatest not getting triggered

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlinx.coroutines.flow

Let's make this simple. I've one `MutableSharedFlow` named `sortOrder` in my `ViewModel`.

```kotlin
private val sortOrder = MutableSharedFlow<String>(
    replay = 0,
    extraBufferCapacity = 1
)
```

I've a `mapLatest` connected to the `sortOrder` to refresh data whenever the `sortOrder` changed.

```kotlin
val data = sortOrder.mapLatest {
    Timber.d("Sort order changed to $it")
    "Sort order is $it"
}
```

I have an observer listening to `data` in the activity.

```kotlin
viewModel.data.asLiveData().observe(this) {
    Timber.d("onCreate: New data is $it")
}
```

and finally, I change the `sortOrder` in `ViewModel`'s `init` method

```kotlin
init {
    sortOrder.tryEmit("year")
}
```

but even after changing the `sortOrder` value, the `mapLatest` not getting triggered. Any idea why?

I am using `MutableSharedFlow` to control the `replay` property to prevent executing `mapLatest` body every time I rotate the screen (or when the activity recreated).

**Full Source Code**

- Full Activity : [TestActivity.kt](https://github.com/theapache64/topcorn2/blob/f410e0c40e1018d6305c796dfbd55663323854e7/app/src/main/java/com/theapache64/topcorn2/ui/test/TestActivity.kt#L30-L32)
- Full ViewModel : [TestViewModel.kt](https://github.com/theapache64/topcorn2/blob/f410e0c40e1018d6305c796dfbd55663323854e7/app/src/main/java/com/theapache64/topcorn2/ui/test/TestViewModel.kt#L19-L22)

> PS: I am new to Flow APIs

Comment: It emits before you observe and you have `0` in replay.

Comment: @MarkKeen I tried `tryEmit` on a button click (after observer registered), it didn't work either.

Comment: So does that return `true` ?

Comment: @MarkKeen Nope. It returns `false`.

Comment: Consider increasing your buffer size, or over flow strategy : https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-mutable-shared-flow/try-emit.html

Comment: @MarkKeen It worked when I did a `clean build`, and you were right about `It emits before you observe and you have 0 in replay.`. Now the problem is the observer is not getting called when activity recreated.

Comment: @MarkKeen I think you can put your answer here. I'll ask a separate question for the observer issue.

Answer (score 2):

The issue seems to be the order in which you're emitting to the flow and collecting from it (with `viewModel.data.asLiveData().observe(...)`). Since you emit (with `tryEmit`) in the construction of the view model, so you cannot be observing at that point. The implementation is in theory the same as this:

```
val sortOrder = MutableSharedFlow<String>(
    replay = 0,
    extraBufferCapacity = 1
)

val data = sortOrder.mapLatest {
    Timber.d("Sort order changed to $it")
    "Sort order is $it"
}

sortOrder.tryEmit("year")

data.asLiveData().observe(this) {
    Timber.d("onCreate: New data is $it")
}
```

The solution depends on your wanted behavior:

If you are okay about the same value potentially be emitted to new collectors, you can simply set `reply = 1` (and then `extraBufferCapacity` can be set to `0`).

The other solution is to make sure `tryEmit` isn't called until after `viewModel.data.asLiveData().observe(...)` is called and make sure that the activity is at least in [resumed state](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/Lifecycle.State#RESUMED) when calling `tryEmit` or else the value is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I think `tryEmit` should be avoided, in cases where you don't have a replay, but still don't want your events to be dropped.

In these cases I'd use `emit()`, which will suspend until a subscriber, in your case `mapLatest` comes into play.

Also in case of a screen-rotation, if the event is emitted while the screen is rotating and you're not listening to the event, you'll get it after the screen-rotation, which I believe is the right UX in most of the cases, but it might depend